# string concatenation and apostrophe marks

Tags: string, matlab

I have a long sql query that I am writing in MATLAB. To make it easier for people to read what is it doing I am trying to break the query on to a few lines rather than one long line.

Below is my code (names changed).

```
sql_statement = strcat('select some_feilds from'...
                       ,' databaseOne.tableOne'...
                       ,' join databaseTwo.tableTwo'...
                       ,' on databaseOne.tableOne.f1 = databaseTwo.tableTwo.f2'...
                       ,' where databaseTwo.tableTwo.f2 =','''', x_lbl(1, 1),'');
```

The issue I have is the x_lbl(1,1) needs an ' either side of it. i.e f2 = 'Health'.

The code above gives me ''Health' which is rather fustrating as when I just the do the line below I get 'Health'. Maybe I'm going blind and losing my mind but can't see to get my query in the correct format?

```
 lbl = strcat('''', x_lbl(1,1), '''');
```

**update**

```
 x_lbl(1,1)
 ans = 'Health Care'


 sql_statement = [1x225 char]
```

that's the answer when using the last line,

```
,' where DVLP_QES.dbo.num_name_mapping.name = ','''', x_lbl(1, 1),'''');
```

Comment: if `x_lbl(1,1)` is a number you can use `num2str`? e.g. `a= strcat('we',num2str(34),'are')`

Comment: hiya sorry should have specified that x_lbl(1,1) is always a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your `sql_statement` to finish like `select [...] tableTwo.f2 ='Health'` you need to add 2 more single quotes at the end of you `strcat`:

```
sql_statement = strcat('select some_feilds from'...
                       ,' databaseOne.tableOne'...
                       ,' join databaseTwo.tableTwo'...
                       ,' on databaseOne.tableOne.f1 = databaseTwo.tableTwo.f2'...
                       ,' where databaseTwo.tableTwo.f2 =','''', x_lbl(1, 1),'''');
```

I supposed `x_lbl(1, 1) = Health` without quotes, right?

**EDIT:**

Using MATLAB R2014a

```
>> x_lbl = 'Health';
>> x_lbl
x_lbl =
Health
>> sql_statement = strcat('select some_feilds from'...
                       ,' databaseOne.tableOne'...
                       ,' join databaseTwo.tableTwo'...
                       ,' on databaseOne.tableOne.f1 = databaseTwo.tableTwo.f2'...
                       ,' where databaseTwo.tableTwo.f2 =','''', x_lbl,'''');
>> sql_statement
sql_statement =
select some_feilds from databaseOne.tableOne join databaseTwo.tableTwo on databaseOne.tableOne.f1 = databaseTwo.tableTwo.f2 where databaseTwo.tableTwo.f2 ='Health'
```

Comment: using '''', x_lbl(1, 1),'''' at the end of my statement actually return ''Health Care'''. Not sure why its different to the single line of code that works

Comment: what is inside `x_lbl(1, 1)` and what's the desired output? is it `[...] tableTwo.f2 ='Health'`?

Comment: Health is inside x_lbl(1,1)

Comment: are you sure  x_lbl(1,1) has no quotes?

Comment: yep no quotes. just Health

Comment: I added just what I did to test, could you please try the same? remember to clear your workspace before testing

Comment: yeh cleaned the workedspace. still not getting the required output though